# signal: segmentation fault (core dumped) Error in C

Tags: c

I’m trying to store a gcode file into An array in C. I can successfully store 50 000 lines but once i try more i get the : signal: segmentation fault (core dumped) error.
Could someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count_lines(char name_file[]){
  FILE* pFile;
  pFile = fopen(name_file,"r");
  char content[100];
  int nbr = 0;
  
  while(fgets(content,100,pFile) != NULL){
    nbr++;
  }

  fclose(pFile);
  return nbr;
}

int main(void) {

  int nbr = count_lines("Lapin.gcode");
  printf("%d\n",nbr);

  nbr = 50000;
  
  FILE* pFile;
  pFile = fopen("Lapin.gcode","r");
  char full_content[nbr+1][100];
  
  for(int i = 0; i<=nbr; i++){
    char sub_content[100];
    fgets(sub_content,100,pFile);
    for(int j = 0;j<=strlen(sub_content);j++){
      full_content[i][j]=sub_content[j];
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i<nbr;i++){
  printf("%s", full_content[i]);
    } 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char full_content[nbr+1][100];`  - `full_content` is allocated on the stack, and it seems to big. You should use `malloc` family to allocate on the heap. Don't forget to `free` the allocated memory when you are done with it.

Comment: Okay, I’ll try using Malloy but how do you interact with the memory allocated

Comment: If you just need to count the number of lines, a re-fillable buffer using `fread` would be easier and faster. You just need to count the new lines, and possibly mal-formed without '\n' delimiting at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your code  does not consider size. You're probably running into an issue as your data is too big. As @wohlstad mentioned, you can switch to using dynamic memory. This may help a bit, but it will still have size limits.
Consider a simplified version of what you have:

```
FILE * file = get_file();
int decas = get_decas(file);

/* allocate enough space for all data */
char buffer[decas][100];

/* get all data at once */
for(int x = 0; x < decas; ++x)
{
  get_another_deca(file, buffer[x]);
}

/* process all data */
for(int x = 0; x < decas; ++x)
{
  printf("%s", buffer[x]);
}
```

This uses statically allocated memory (`buffer`) and reads the whole file before processing.

The below would help you to use dynamic memory

```
FILE * file = get_file();
int decas = get_deca(file);


/* allocate space for the file to be read in */
char* buffer[decas];
for(int x = 0; x < decas; ++x)
{
  buffer[x] = (char*)malloc(100);
}

/* get all data at once */
for(int x = 0; x < decas; ++x)
{
  get_another_deca(file, buffer[x]);
}

/* process all data at once */
for(int x = 0; x < decas; ++x)
{
  printf("%s", buffer[x]);
}

/* return allocated memory */
for(int x = 0; x < decas; ++x)
{
  free(buffer[x]);
}
```

Again, this will only get you so far. If your file is big it still won't work. The below will change the algorithm to not care how many lines are in your file.

```
FILE * file = get_file();
int decas = get_deca(file);

/* allocate space for one deca only */

char buffer[100];

/* for each iteration:
  - get only one piece of data and process it
  - do not store the data, rewrite it on the next iteration */
for(int x = 0; x < decas; ++x)
{
  get_another_deca(buffer, file);
  printf("%s", buffer[x]);
}
```

Note 1:
All the code snippets use *deca*. I'm just using this as in your given example you seem to use units of 100. I'm not familiar with the type of file youre working with so I'm keeping it at deca. In other formats this may be renamed as "line".

Note 2:
This type of algorithm will work as long as each deca is independant of all other decas (it is in the simplified example you wrote in the question). If for instance, one piece of data relies on the previous piece, then you'll have to store two pieces at once.
If your entire file is dependent on the rest of the file....this answer doesn't help you as it's going to be bit more involved to solve that problem.